# Difference in DocumentBuilder.parse when using JRE 1.5 and JDK 1.6

Tags: java, xml, parsing, sax, java-6

Recently at last we have switched our projects to Java 1.6. When executing the tests I found out that using 1.6 a SAXParseException is not thrown which has been thrown using 1.5.

Below is my test code to demonstrate the problem.

```
import java.io.StringReader;

import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamSource;
import javax.xml.validation.SchemaFactory;

import org.junit.Test;
import org.xml.sax.InputSource;
import org.xml.sax.SAXParseException;


/**
 * Test class to demonstrate the difference between JDK 1.5 to JDK 1.6.
 * 
 * Seen on Linux:
 * 
 * <pre>
 * #java version "1.6.0_18"
 * Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_18-b07)
 * Java HotSpot(TM) Server VM (build 16.0-b13, mixed mode)
 * </pre>
 * 
 * Seen on OSX:
 * 
 * <pre>
 * java version "1.6.0_17"
 * Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_17-b04-248-10M3025)
 * Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 14.3-b01-101, mixed mode)
 * </pre>
 * 
 * @author dhiller (creator)
 * @author $Author$ (last editor)
 * @version $Revision$
 * @since 12.03.2010 11:32:31
 */
public class TestXMLValidation {

  /**
   * Tests the schema validation of an XML against a simple schema.
   * 
   * @throws Exception
   *           Falls ein Fehler auftritt
   * @throws junit.framework.AssertionFailedError
   *           Falls eine Unit-Test-Pruefung fehlschlaegt
   */
  @Test(expected = SAXParseException.class)
  public void testValidate() throws Exception {
    final StreamSource schema = new StreamSource( new StringReader( "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>"
      + "<xs:schema xmlns:xs=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\" "
      + "elementFormDefault=\"qualified\" xmlns:xsd=\"undefined\">" + "<xs:element name=\"Test\"/>" + "</xs:schema>" ) );
    final String xml = "<Test42/>";
    final DocumentBuilderFactory newFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    newFactory.setSchema( SchemaFactory.newInstance( "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" ).newSchema( schema ) );
    final DocumentBuilder documentBuilder = newFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
    documentBuilder.parse( new InputSource( new StringReader( xml ) ) );
  }

}
```

When using a JVM 1.5 the test passes, on 1.6 it fails with "Expected exception SAXParseException".

The Javadoc of the [DocumentBuilderFactory.setSchema(Schema)](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/parsers/DocumentBuilderFactory.html#setSchema(javax.xml.validation.Schema)) Method says:

> When errors are found by the
>   validator, the parser is responsible
>   to report them to the user-specified
>   ErrorHandler (or if the error handler
>   is not set, ignore them or throw
>   them), just like any other errors
>   found by the parser itself. In other
>   words, if the user-specified
>   ErrorHandler is set, it must receive
>   those errors, and if not, they must be
>   treated according to the
>   implementation specific default error
>   handling rules.

The Javadoc of the [DocumentBuilder.parse(InputSource)](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/parsers/DocumentBuilder.html#parse(org.xml.sax.InputSource)) method says:

BTW: I tried setting an error handler via [setErrorHandler](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/parsers/DocumentBuilder.html#setErrorHandler(org.xml.sax.ErrorHandler)), but there still is no exception.

Now my question:

What has changed to 1.6 that prevents the schema validation to throw a SAXParseException? Is it related to the schema or to the xml that I tried to parse?

**Update:**

The following code works on 1.5 and 1.6 as I've been desiring:

```
  @Test(expected = SAXParseException.class)
  public void testValidate() throws Exception {
    final StreamSource schema = new StreamSource( new StringReader( "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>"
      + "<xs:schema xmlns:xs=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\" "
      + "elementFormDefault=\"qualified\" xmlns:xsd=\"undefined\">" + "<xs:element name=\"Test\"/>" + "</xs:schema>" ) );
    final String xml = "<Test42/>";
    final DocumentBuilderFactory newFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    final Schema newSchema = SchemaFactory.newInstance( "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" ).newSchema( schema );
    newFactory.setSchema( newSchema );
    final Validator newValidator = newSchema.newValidator();
    final Source is = new StreamSource( new StringReader( xml ) );
    try {
      newValidator.validate( ( Source ) is );
    }
    catch ( Exception e ) {
      e.printStackTrace();
      throw e;
    }
    final DocumentBuilder documentBuilder = newFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
    documentBuilder.parse( new InputSource( new StringReader( xml ) ) );
  }
```

The solution seems to be to explicitly using a Validator instance created from the Schema instance.
I've found the solution [here](https://jira.jboss.org/jira/browse/JBESB-2922)

Still I'm not sure why that is...

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, a document not complying with the schema only merits a mild rebuke on stderr from the default error handler.  My solution was to replace the default error handler with a stricter one:

```
// builder is my DocumentBuilder
builder.setErrorHandler(new ErrorHandler() {
    @Override
    public void error(SAXParseException arg0) throws SAXException {
        throw arg0;             
    }

    @Override
    public void fatalError(SAXParseException arg0) throws SAXException {
        throw arg0;                 
    }

    @Override
    public void warning(SAXParseException arg0) throws SAXException {
        throw arg0;                 
    }
});
```